Manager is asking for taking more responsibility, but I feel like I am being constantly monitored at work
I joined a team some 4-5 months back. There are around 6-7 projects in our team's responsibility. There is no proper documentation for any of the projects, or the code. Even some architecture documents were missing. There are 8 people, but 3 are related to our technology and 1 overall team lead.
One of the veterans of the project has worked in the team (let's call him X) for 3+ years, and has worked on at least 4 of the above projects.  He has recently announced that he is leaving. He is also one level higher than me in terms of our company hierarchy. We decided that we would get KT sessions from him.
We follow an Agile method. Out of nowhere, I got a call from the team lead. He said that X has set a higher standard. The client that I work for has seen me as a promising candidate, but in the last sprint, I saw a downward trend. The team lead wants me to take more responsibility to be as good as X. The team lead said that even though there is one more person under our team (let's call him Y) of which the client has no expectations. Our client is leaning on me.
This hit me like a loaded truck. Because of little to no documentation, I'd been straining to get the work done. I'd been going around asking people for help to understand the code so that I could deliver the output.
I went ahead and told the team lead exactly what I'd been doing. He finally he concluded that I'd been putting in great effort, but the same was not known to the client. I also told the lead that the person Y was somewhat inexperienced and had made mistakes, and that I'd taken it over, and made it better. Also, I made some changes in the format in writing the code (which were different from the other existing projects) to improve readability and maintainability. I also challenged the team lead to go through the code base and see the changes.
The team lead said that I should discuss such things even more, with the client. I was actually new the project when I completed that work, so I didn't discuss. She said that I need to take more responsibility from now, and even assigned some small tasks.
After this discussion, I thought - how can anyone judge a work based on just one sprint (14 days) ? Some sprints will be monotonous and dull. Some work will just need to be done. It is not possible to always deliver exceptional outcome.
Now, I feel very nervous. I feel as if I will be constantly monitored to deliver more and more (which I don't think, is possible every time). I also feel like I got a quiet promotion, which means more responsibility but without more pay.
Please tell me what I can do so that I can do my work peacefully without feeling overburdened. I cannot work while being constantly monitored. I am already aware that there are expectations of me, but adding more responsibilities is a bit too much for me.

What’s the problem? It sounds like you are trusted by your peers and supervisors, are being offered opportunities to excel at your job, you have a good problem. You have done too good of a job.

@Donald I know it is a good problem. But, this discussion makes me feel like I will be expected to deliver exceptional results in every sprint. I dont think that is possible. But more than that, I feel like I will always be watched. That worries me

The interesting question in my mind: why does the Client have such a detailed knowledge of all the team members, so they can make HR decisions about their role in the company? "Client has no expectations from Y. Client has more expectations from me"

@virolino No idea why they have detailed knowledge or even need it. so they can make HR decisions about their role in the company? - what does this mean ?

@pc_fuel: A promotion is a job shared between your manager and the HR. Promotions of team members are mostly never involving clients.

@virolino Client does not care about my promotion. Client and Team lead wants me to take as many responsibilities as the Person X. However, Person X was one level higher than me in our company, so it came with added salary.

@pc_fuel in a healthy work environment nobody is expected to be at their peak (let alone above it) at all times. If you feel you're pressured to hard, take it up with your scrum master, team lead, or whoever in your team is responsible for such things.

@pc_fuel - Yes; You have raised the bar on your ability to output quality work.

@pc_fuel: I already quoted this once, I highlight it again: "Client has more expectations from me" What you wrote means that the client is somehow directly involved in the decision process. A client should not even know that you exists. Or that Y exists. They should only know about the sales department in your company and the project manager. Everyone else is supposed to be hidden / protected. At least, that is according to my experience.


Thing is, there is no proper documentation for any project. And no documentation on coding parts. Even some architecture documents were missing.

That is the problem with most projects in most companies. If you will go somewhere else, things will not be much better in this regard.

EDIT (based on comment from @jwenting - thank you)
You need to clarify with the people responsible for you and your work (manager, team lead, whatever they are called, they can have many names) and understand what is the proposed change: the exact new responsibilities and the exact salary increase - and other benefits. If you do not have enough information, you can make not-so-good decisions.

As I see it, you are at a cross-roads. I cannot decide for you, but I will try to present some of your alternatives:

You are regarded as a good professional. Accept the challenge and go forward.
You really do not want to advance in your career at this time. The tell your manager clearly that you do not want the promotion. While he might accept your refusal, there might be consequences. Both he and the client might feel disappointed / betrayed / offended and only the Creator knows what they might decide.
You refuse the promotion, and the manager and the Client are both nice and professional, and they will accept your decision without bad feelings. You might have other options for promotion in the future.
Feel afraid of everything that is going on and search for another job at another company.

BUT...
these options are not equal to each other. I evaluate them like this:

Even though it might feel frightening, it is quite acceptable. It might even come with a salary increase (which you are entitled to request).
Quite likely to actually happen. Especially because the Client has the power to make decisions in your company.
Quite unlikely.
Read again what I wrote at the beginning. There is no perfect company. The benefit here is that you already know what is not-so-good, and you are already able to deal with it. You know nothing of the internal dynamics in a new company (who loves whom, who hates whom...).

So if you go with option 1 (the least hurting, if not the most beneficial), you have the opportunity to learn new things: technical, political, also you will meet new people. And on top of everything, you might have a chance to lead the things in such way to make that documentation appear where there was no documentation before.


I feel like, I will be constantly monitored

You, me, and everyone else, we are already being constantly monitored. By colleagues, by managers, by the traffic cameras and the security cameras at the supermarket etc. From this point of view, nothing will change.


I got a quiet promotion = more responsibility, but without pay.

As I already wrote above: request that pay. You might not get a lot (or anything), but at least be active about your own interests.
If they give you reasons to not give you a salary increase, then you should demand a clear roadmap with S.M.A.R.T. objectives, at the end of which you will have X amount of salary / benefits (better than now).

I am more concerned about the feedback that I slacked off, even when I was busting my ass for work. That hurt me. And that is the reason, why I am afraid to take the quiet promotion. Also, I am 100% certain that there will not be a hike

@pc_fuel talk about it with the people making those comments. Quite possibly they weren't intended as you state, if they were you're in a toxic work environment and would probably follow your predecessor's decision and move on to another job (though very few companies never have such problems).

There is a big difference between an actual manager and person having tasks being dumped on them.
A manager reviews what the situation is, what the desired situation is, and comes up with several reasonable paths to get there.
A manager expects to promptly and perodically report progress, impediments, and requirements. Being monitored is part of the job. The level of monitoring is inverse to the amount of built up trust and risk.
A manager should be compensated for their skills.
A person that has extra tasks dumped on them without a clear explaination from their manager and is left somewhat confused about the longterm expectations.
If you want to be the person that leads getting the proper documentation and maintenance protocols in place then consider stepping up and asking to be formally made into a manager with the role, responsibility, and pay.
If not, remind them of your other duties that will be affected and how it will harm your productivity. It won't be a surprise that they will stilll try to push more onto you anyway.
But keep in mind, your company sees in you the capability to do more than you are now. You see a problem. This is an opportunity for career growth if you want it. Where do you see yourself in 5 years?
